# How to .Map over different props that are passed into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm new to React but hopefully someone can help!

So I've just created a component that takes in a value (via prop) and then .maps over that value creating an Image slider. The props are all an array of objects that contain different values such as :

```js
const Songs = [
  {
      artist: 'Artist Name',
      song: 'Song Name',
      lenght: '2:36',
      poster: 'images/....jpg'
  },
   {
      artist: 'Artist Name',
      song: 'Song Name',
      lenght: '2:36',
      poster: 'images/....jpg'
  },
 
 ]
```

I have been making the same component over and over again because I don't know how to make the 'prop'.map value dynamic. Essentially I don't know how to change the value before the .map each different prop.

Here's an example. I want to make 'Songs'.map dynamic so the new props can replace that so they can also be mapped. Maybe there's another way. Hopefully some can help.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FaCaretDown } from 'react-icons/fa';


function ImageSlider({Songs, KidsMovies, Movies, TvShows}) {
    return (
        <>
        
           {Songs.map((image, index) => (

            <div className="movie-card">

                 <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + image.poster_path}
                 className='movie-img' />
                 
                 <h5 className='movie-card-desc'>{image.original_title}</h5>
                 <p className='movie-card-overview'>{movie.overview}</p>
        
            </div>
            

           ))}

         
           
        </>
    );
}


export default ImageSlider;
```

Comment: **I've also tried to copy and paste the .map function using the different prop values. That also didn't work **

Answer (score 2):

Given your example,

I feel like all you need is render ImageSlides for each array

```
function ImageSlider({ items }) {
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item, idx) => (
        <div ... key={idx}> // be careful to not forget to put a key when you map components
          ...
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

When rendering your component

```
function OtherComponent({ songs, kidsMovies, movies, tvShows }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ImageSlider items={songs} />
      <ImageSlider items={kidsMovies} />
      <ImageSlider items={movies} />
      <ImageSlider items={tvShows} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shantr, so is 'items' in the ImageSlider function being replaced by the prop thats passed in?

Comment: Exactly, the first ImageSlider being rendered would get `songs` as `items` prop and so on

Comment: Exactly, the first ImageSlider being rendered would get `songs` as `items` prop and so on.

What feels a bit unclear in you question, is that songs, kidsMovies, movies and tvShows are probably not of the schema
In this case, the exemple above may not work. (for instance song does not seems to have the field `original_title` that is used by your ImageSlider component).

Maybe what you are looking for is a way to render dynamically depending on the items fields ?

Comment: Thank you. I know what you mean lol it wouldn't work.  That's only something that I copied and pasted quick to show what I was taking about .